# Error initializing filter 'pan' with args 'stereo:c0<c0+c2:c1<c1+c3'

Tags: android, video, ffmpeg, android-ffmpeg

I run below FFmpeg command to merge audio and video keeping video's original audio using FFmpeg 4.0-39 version-

```
-i /storage/emulated/0/Movies/extract_audio.mp3 -i /storage/emulated/0/Movies/VID-20200501-WA0000.mp4 -filter_complex [0:a][1:a]amerge,pan=stereo:c0<c0+c2:c1<c1+c3[out] -map 1:v -map [out] -c:v copy -c:a aac -shortest /storage/emulated/0/Movies/merge_video.mp4
```

It fails for all videos with below error !However same command runs fine when using older version 3.0.1 of FFMpeg !

```
FAILED with output : ffmpeg version n4.0-39-gda39990 Copyright (c) 2000-2018 the FFmpeg developers
      built with gcc 4.9.x (GCC) 20150123 (prerelease)
      configuration: --target-os=linux --cross-prefix=/root/bravobit/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/bin/arm-linux-androideabi- --arch=arm --cpu=cortex-a8 --enable-runtime-cpudetect --sysroot=/root/bravobit/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/sysroot --enable-pic --enable-libx264 --enable-ffprobe --enable-libopus --enable-libvorbis --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libmp3lame --enable-fontconfig --enable-libvpx --enable-libass --enable-yasm --enable-pthreads --disable-debug --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --disable-ffplay --disable-linux-perf --disable-doc --disable-shared --enable-static --enable-runtime-cpudetect --enable-nonfree --enable-network --enable-avresample --enable-avformat --enable-avcodec --enable-indev=lavfi --enable-hwaccels --enable-ffmpeg --enable-zlib --enable-gpl --enable-small --enable-nonfree --pkg-config=pkg-config --pkg-config-flags=--static --prefix=/root/bravobit/ffmpeg-android/build/armeabi-v7a --extra-cflags='-I/root/bravobit/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/include -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fno-strict-overflow -fstack-protector-all' --extra-ldflags='-L/root/bravobit/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/lib -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -pie' --extra-cxxflags=
      libavutil      56. 14.100 / 56. 14.100
      libavcodec     58. 18.100 / 58. 18.100
      libavformat    58. 12.100 / 58. 12.100
      libavdevice    58.  3.100 / 58.  3.100
      libavfilter     7. 16.100 /  7. 16.100
      libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
      libswscale      5.  1.100 /  5.  1.100
      libswresample   3.  1.100 /  3.  1.100
      libpostproc    55.  1.100 / 55.  1.100
    Input #0, mp3, from '/storage/emulated/0/Movies/extract_audio.mp3.mp4':
      Metadata:
        major_brand     : M4V 
        minor_version   : 512
        compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1
        encoder         : Lavf58.12.100
      Duration: 00:00:20.04, start: 0.025057, bitrate: 256 kb/s
        Stream #0:0: Audio: mp3, 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 256 kb/s
        Metadata:
          encoder         : Lavc58.18
    Input #1, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/storage/emulated/0/Movies/VID-20200501-WA0000.mp4.mp4':
      Metadata:
        major_brand     : isom
        minor_version   : 512
        compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
        encoder         : Lavf58.20.100
      Duration: 00:00:09.83, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 809 kb/s
        Stream #1:0(und): Video: h264 (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 480x600, 737 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 tbn, 60 tbc (default)
        Metadata:
          handler_name    : VideoHandler
        Stream #1:1(und): Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 64 kb/s (default)
        Metadata:
          handler_name    : SoundHandler
    [Parsed_pan_1 @ 0xaef0c000] This syntax is deprecated. Use '|' to separate the list items ('stereo|c0<c0+c2|c1<c1+c3' instead of 'stereo:c0<c0+c2:c1<c1+c3')
    [AVFilterGraph @ 0xaf117180] Error initializing filter 'pan' with args 'stereo:c0<c0+c2:c1<c1+c3'
    Error initializing complex filters.
    Invalid argument
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new syntax is `pan=stereo|c0<c0+c2|c1<c1+c3`. It's a single argument delimited by `|` and parsed by an parser intrinsic to `pan`. Quote the argument depending on your shell/wrapper.

Comment: Thanks for your answer..is their doc which can highlight all the code level changes that are introduced in each version so that migration from old ffmpeg version to new ffmpeg version becomes easy?

Comment: Not for changes to private API such as filter arguments.